# Github PR triggers push workflows unexpectedly

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api, github-actions-workflows

I have a a build workflow and a deploy workflow.

```
name: Deploy Staging API & Web

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
```

```
name: Build Api

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - release
```

When I create a pull request from `release-10-19` into `release`, it triggers the `Deploy Staging API & Web` workflow with the trigger `push`!
[image: pr]
[image: checks]

How is it possible that there is a `push` event that triggers the `Deploy Staging API & Web` when the PR is from `release-10-19 -> release`?

As an outcome, I would like the `Deploy Staging API & Web` workflow to only run on pushes to the `master` branch, as I think I have it configured.

Comment: How's `release-10-19` created? From the tip of `master`, perhaps?

Comment: Yes: `git checkout -b release-10-19 origin/master`, then `git push origin release-10-19`, and then create the PR in the Github UI to merge release-10-19 into release.

Comment: I guess because the new branch points to the tip of master, pushing it is considered a push on master, too. You could dump the `github` context to see if there's a property you can filter on to exclude these pushes.

Comment: The workflow doesn't trigger when I push the release-10-19 branch, it happens when I open the PR though